# Change Animation Style for a Popup Window programmatically

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have a `PopupWindow` and i set an Animation Style to it, like this (I omit trivial code like declarations and animation parameters: trust me, it works):

```
<style name="fade_and_scale" parent "android:Animation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_and_scale_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_and_scale_out</item>
</style>
```

and

```
popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.fade_and_scale);
```

What if I wanted to change the animation parameters, like... speed, or max alpha? Currently the animation is defined in a xml.

Please note that Animation Style is not Animation and a traditional Animation, as far as I know, cannot be applied to a PopupWindow.

I already saw that there are quite a few questions about programmatically change an animation style for a popup window, without any answer, but... I'm optimistic and hope that in the meantime something changed and now maybe it's possible? :) Maybe, if there is not a *direct* solution to this question, there is a different way to achieve the same result?